# Invalid Access Token Spring Boot Resource Server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have a Spring Boot Resource Server, like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

And a endpoint like this:

```
@RestController
public class TestResourceOne {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestResourceOne.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/calcsqrt")
    public Double calcSqtr(@RequestParam("value") Double value) {
        return Math.sqrt(value);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sum")
    public Double calcSqtr(@RequestParam("value1") Double value1, @RequestParam("value2") Double value2) {
        return value1 + value2;
    }
}
```

My Authorization Server is in Azure AD, so when i call this endpoint "/calcsqrt" i pass the Bearer Token generated by Azure. This is my request:

```
GET /serviceone/calcsqrt?value=3 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Authorization: Bearer MY_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: ef5d493c-39f1-4bc4-9084-4ea510ac1255
```

But i always get the following error from spring:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "Invalid access token: MY_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE"
}
```

Comment: Which access token converter are you using on resource server?

Comment: I'm not using any converter

Comment: In that you need to use some token services(e.g. RemoteTokenServices) which you can use to validate your token.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your resource config class was wrong. i have implemented resource config like this

```
package com.ig.user.config;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.UserInfoTokenServices;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;

/**
 * @author Jai
 *
 */
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ResourceConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private final String userInfoUri = "url";

    private final String clientId = "foo";

    @Override
    public void configure(final ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId("user");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v1/user/activate/**").permitAll()//
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public UserInfoTokenServices tokenService() {
        final UserInfoTokenServices tokenService = new UserInfoTokenServices(userInfoUri, clientId);
        return tokenService;
    }
}
```

**EDIT-1**

- *userInfoUri* is the URL which gives the Authorization for this resource
- *resourceId* For every resource server we have to create one resourceId and that the same id we have to keep in where you are storing the client details

Hope it will help you out

Comment: Can you explain the resourceID and UserInfoTokenServices?

Comment: While creating resource server, you must create resource-id. u have to use the same resource id where you are storing the client details

Comment: About userInfoUri . In Oauth2 i have /token and /authorize , which URL i should use here ?